# Logs are written to server.log instead of a separate log

Tags: jboss, log4j

I have a simple SOAP based application writing to a separate log.  The log is created under jboss/bin/log, but it's empty. I deploy the web services as a jar file to JBoss AS 6.1.   The log4j.properties is under the root directory of ‘src’ folder.

```
package abc.WebServiceSamples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "GreetingService")
public class greeting {
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(greeting.class);

public greeting() {
    super();
}

@WebMethod
public String welcome(String s1) {
    String str = "Welcome,  " + s1;

    Properties props = new Properties();

    //load from classpath
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");

    // Now pass these properties to PropertyConfigurator
    try {
        props.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

   logger.debug("Sample debug message");
   logger.info("Sample info message");
   logger.warn("Sample warn message");
   logger.error("Sample error message");
   logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");

    return str;
}
```

}

```
log4j.properties:

log4j.rootLogger=INFO

# AdminFileAppender - used to log messages in the admin.log file.
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.File=log/admin.log
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# ReportFileAppender - used to log messages in the report.log file.
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.File=log/report.log
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

#log4j.logger.com.vaannila.admin=,AdminFileAppender
log4j.logger.abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting=,ReportFileAppender
```

java run command:

/opt/java/bin/java -server -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/bin/logging.properties -Dlog4j.debug=true -Djava.library.path=/opt/jboss/bin/native/lib64 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jboss/lib/endorsed -classpath /opt/jboss/bin/run.jar:/opt/java/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main -c all -b 0.0.0.0

tailing server/all/server.log:

2012-08-06 15:21:33,688 INFO [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (HDScanner) deploy, ctxPath=/ejb_ws_greeting
2012-08-06 15:21:50,929 INFO [STDOUT] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [OtherAppender].
2012-08-06 15:21:50,930 INFO [STDOUT] (Finalizer) log4j: Finalizing appender named [ReportFileAppender].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,156 INFO [org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet transport factory already registered
2012-08-06 15:22:37,164 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,165 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Level token is [INFO].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,169 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Category root set to null
2012-08-06 15:22:37,169 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Parsing for [abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting] with value=[WARN,ReportFileAppender ].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,169 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Level token is [WARN].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,169 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: **Category abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting set to null**
2012-08-06 15:22:37,169 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Parsing appender named "ReportFileAppender".
2012-08-06 15:22:37,170 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Parsing layout options for "ReportFileAppender".
2012-08-06 15:22:37,170 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,171 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: End of parsing for "ReportFileAppender".
2012-08-06 15:22:37,171 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Setting property [file] to [log/report1.log].
2012-08-06 15:22:37,171 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: setFile called: log/report1.log, true
2012-08-06 15:22:37,171 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: setFile ended
2012-08-06 15:22:37,171 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Parsed "ReportFileAppender" options.
2012-08-06 15:22:37,171 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting=[null]
2012-08-06 15:22:37,172 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) log4j: Finished configuring.
2012-08-06 15:22:37,172 INFO [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Welcome, Hi  cool
2012-08-06 15:22:37,172 WARN [abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Sample warn message
2012-08-06 15:22:37,172 ERROR [abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Sample error message
2012-08-06 15:22:37,172 FATAL [abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Sample fatal message

Thank you.

Comment: which log file is empty? report.log?

Comment: report.log. Also, I wrote a simple program to call the same webservice library, and it writes logs to the file. So, I guess it has something to do how JBoss logging works. thx

Comment: I suspect that "Category abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting set to null" causing all the logs going to server.log.

Comment: have you tried with `log4j.logger.abc.WebServiceSamples.greeting=WARN,ReportFileAppender`?

Comment: any update Will L? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A solution of a similar problem could be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924040

Basically it excludes the module org.apache.log4j from your deployment unit, because there might be a conflict between log4j and the default logging implementation of the application server.