# JBoss server.log remove entries "WARN org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters.DecimalLocaleConverter - No pattern provided, using default."

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, jboss, log4j

We use JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8). In our server.log file
there are many log-entries

```
 WARN [org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters.DecimalLocaleConverter]    No pattern provided, using default.
```

we need to remove.

The problem is that I am not sure if these messages do really come from our own application (let us called it UKApp) or not, since our JBoss server hosts a number of applications, not just our UKApp. Besides, our application UKApp uses log4j and does have its own log4.properties configuration file, which contains the rows:

```
# struts packages
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR, R
```

as well as the rows

```
# Rolling file appender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${LOG_ROOT}/Applications/UKApp.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n
# Set the max size of the file and the number of backup files
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=2000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3
```

Indeed, it is possible that our application UKApp may indireclty use the apache class

`org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters.DecimalLocaleConverter`

and, more specifically, its method call

```
DecimalLocaleConverter.convert(int, null);
```

which does output the warning message cited above.

But: This call may probably be  used by other applications as well. Also,  according to our configuration file, we set the log level of the entire package org.apache to ERROR, and we output to the R appender:

```
# struts packages
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR, R
```

which, in this case, is our own file ${LOG_ROOT}/Applications/UKApp.log, and not the general server.log

Does this mean, that the warning message DOES NOT really come from our application UKApp?

Thank you!

Kind reagrds: Alexander Mintchev

Comment: Are you calling `DecimalLocaleConverter.convert(int, null);` from your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having carefully read other posts, such as:

[log4j - how to log to seperate/different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904421/log4j-how-to-log-to-seperate-different-files/26924040#26924040)

we noticed that our `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` configuration file contains the following `exlusions` section:

```
<exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
</exclusions>
```

However, we also noticed that `<dependencies>` section preceding the `<exclusions>` section looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="org.picketlink" slot="main"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xalan" slot="main"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xerces" slot="main"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
    <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" slot="main" export="true"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" slot="main" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" slot="main" export="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

Apparently, the `org.apache.commons.logging` entry was presented in both `<dependencies>` and `<exclusions>` sections.

We removed the entry from the `<dependencies>` section and it solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the method `DecimalLocaleConverter.convert(int, null);` then use the statement `DecimalLocaleConverter.convert(int, "##,###.##");`

Comment: Actually, we do not use this method call directly - it might be used by one of the jars we are referring. But: I created my small test application, which directly uses the class and the above mentioned method call just to test the logging. In my small test application I added the configuration entry

Comment: Then, It is just a warning, ignore it.

Comment: log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters.DecimalLocaleConverter=WARN, stdout, R                                                                                  and the message went to our own custom log-file, not to server.log

Comment: Actually, I must clean server.log file from all these messages